# How do I convert a polygon to a raster so that the pixels are the same as the polgons

Tags: terra, rasterizing

I have the following shape file and I want to convert the polygons into raster with pixels.

How do I do that so that the pixels have the same resolution (size) as the polygons (or close to it)?

```
library(terra)
TKshape <- vect("/TK_25_shape_crs_wgs84.shp")

TKshape

class       : SpatVector 
 geometry    : polygons 
 dimensions  : 1240, 19  (geometries, attributes)
 extent      : 7.499192, 10.49876, 47.49912, 49.79888  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
 source      : TK_25_shape_crs_wgs84.shp
 coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
 names       : OBJECTID OBJECT_ID   NAME RECHTSWERT  HOCHWERT  MER_LU_X  MER_LU_Y  MER_RU_X  MER_RU_Y  MER_LO_X (and 9 more)
 type        :    <int>     <num>  <chr>      <num>     <num>     <num>     <num>     <num>     <num>     <num>             
 values      :      505       515 7313SO  4.232e+05 5.386e+06 4.201e+05 5.383e+06 4.262e+05 5.383e+06 4.201e+05             
                    506       516 7313SW   4.17e+05 5.386e+06 4.139e+05 5.384e+06 4.201e+05 5.383e+06  4.14e+05             
                    507       517 7314NO  4.355e+05 5.392e+06 4.324e+05 5.389e+06 4.386e+05 5.389e+06 4.325e+05
```

It should be possible with

```
rr <-rasterize(TKshape, r, "name")
```

But how do I create the right raster object to match my polygon?

Comment: Please edit your question and include a *minimal, self-contained, reproducible example*. That is always expected when asking an R question (and there are 1000s of examples that show how to do it) but especially in this case as it is not clear what you are asking, exactly. There is no general "match"; perhaps what you ask for makes sense for your specific polygons; but we would need an example to be able to respond.

Comment: Thank you Robert. I kinda found out what the the problem was. I needed the nrow and ncol for the new raster. So I needed the count of the polygons horizontal and vertical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem.

To use rasterize i needed ncol and nrow for the new raster which was the count of the polygons horizontaly and verticaly. So I counted :)

```
r <- rast(TKshape, ncols=34, nrows=46)
temp <- rasterize(TKshape, r)
```

```
plot(TKshape)
```

[image: TKshape]

```
plot(temp)
```

[image: temp]